# Angular 4 [Material 2] Karma Test shows Material Components over Karma output

Tags: angular, angular-material, karma-runner

i writing an Angular 4 app with Angluar Material 2 as Style Framework.
When i test my application karma shows some Angular Material Components over the output and it doesn't disappear.

[image]

it would be nice if i can suppress this.